# How to use DistributedDataParallel() and init_process_group() in a HPC?

Tags: pytorch

I will use HPC for my research and I don't know a lot about parallel or distributed computing. 
I really don't understand the `DistributedDataParallel()` in pytorch. Especially `init_process_group()`.
What is the meaning of initializing processes group? and what is

> init_method : URL specifying how to initialize the package.

for example (I found those in the documentation):
`'tcp://10.1.1.20:23456'` or `'file:///mnt/nfs/sharedfile'`
What are those URLs?

What is the Rank of the current process?
Is `world_size` the number of GPUs?

It would be really appreciated if someone explained to me what is and How to use `DistributedDataParallel()` and `init_process_group()` because I don't know parallel or distributed computing.

I will use things like Slurm(sbatch) in the HPC.